# Upload an image on Facebook via FBConnect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, fbconnect

I know many question has been post and answer for this question. I still stuck by a little thing.
I did success upload an `UIImage` on Facebook via my iPhone app but I realize that photos goes to a pending album. And user had to accept it to get it post on their wall.

Here is my code

```
- (void)start
{
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"read_stream", @"offline_access", nil];
    [_fbEngine authorize:kFbAppId
             permissions:permissions
                delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FBSession delegate

- (void)fbDidLogin 
{

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   self.image, @"picture",
                                   nil];
    [_fbEngine requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"
                           andParams:params
                       andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                         andDelegate:self];
}
```

Is there a way to post a photo directly on the wall without passing by the pending album.

Regards,
KL94

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@"publish_stream"` to your list of requested permissions.

That'll let you push straight to their wall without an intermediate step. `@"offline_access"` would allow you to do that via the graph api instead of with a FBDialog, too, so you could make the post happen entirely in the background.